# Unstoppable force

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,
and just relax here at the top of my column. 
Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle, 
but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

Typically speaking I reach senses of three, 
when you count those senses, you may find me. 
For if you hold me, I'm likely dead, 
why did you take me away from my bed?

Out of the rainbow I cannot see blue, 
and my name can be split into two. 
The first part of me is a computer's worst dream, 
while the second one comes apart at the seam.

Back in the 30's I caused a great craze, 
not one single chap did I cease to amaze. 
Everyone loved me and wanted a kiss, 
but then in the 40's screamed "What did I miss?"

I came with a flash and out like a light, 
but I don't really mind because life is so bright. 
I've been explosive at one point in history, 
what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

Part 4. Good Luck!

Hint... Every line contains at least one hint (except for the last) so if you find something that doesn't fit a line, it may not be right.

Additional Hint... a lot of the hints in the poem reference a part of the word.

Comment: Added another stanza.

Comment: Your new stanzas really force the thought of some kind of flower into my head, but it doesn't fit all of the clues.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha The *original* stanzas forced a thought of a specific kind of flower into my head, but less so now, haha

Comment: Teeheehee. Good riddle?

Comment: Does it ever hurt to guess? @question_asker

Comment: another stanza... its about that time ;)

Comment: I've never even *heard* of a "viruspantstoosmall"

Comment: @question_asker Hahahaha. Not how the new stanza was meant to be interpreted. Took me a second to get it. XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> Tulip

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,
and just relax here at the top of my column.

> Tulip flower is on top of the "column" — stem.

Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,

> Reference to *tiptoe through the tulips*?

but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> As several other answers already mentioned, *Pistil* is a part of flower.

Typically speaking I reach senses of three,
when you count those senses, you may find me.

> Visual, smell and touch senses. Two groups of 3 petals. It is common to "count" petals on a flower.

For if you hold me, I'm likely dead,
why did you take me away from my bed?

> You picked a flower from flowerbed and killed it. You monster.

Out of the rainbow I cannot see blue,

> There are no natural blue tulips. All "blue" ones are actually more or less violet.

and my name can be split into two.
The first part of me is a computer's worst dream,
while the second one comes apart at the seam.

> I cannot make head or tails of "Tu", but "lip"s are coming apart at a seam

Back in the 30's I caused a great craze,
not one single chap did I cease to amaze.
Everyone loved me and wanted a kiss,
but then in the 40's screamed "What did I miss?"

> [Tulip mania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip_mania) of 1630's

I came with a flash and out like a light,
but I don't really mind because life is so bright.

> Possible short flowering cycle.

I've been explosive at one point in history,

> USS Tulip exploded in 1864

Comment: The couple hints missed you can add to your answer. Count one, TWO, three. Whistle references both tiptoe through the tulips and that lips are used to whistle. Again counting referencing a number as part of it. Computers worst dream "2". flash BULB light BULB also references the speed of tulip mania. Bright colors. Explosive referenced USS Tulip and the explosion in price during the mania.

Answer (score 11):

I am

> Horatio Nelson

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,

> Lord Horatio Nelson was the **first** Vis**count** Nelson.

and just relax here at the top of my column.

> His figure is on top of [Nelson's Column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson's_Column) in pretty relaxed pose.

Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,

> There are [several ships and even ship classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Nelson) named after Nelson, and ship's signal is commonly called *whistle*. Alternatively, he was a naval officer and it is expected that ships where he was on signalled with a whistle as any other ship.

but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> Only weapon you can expect naval officer to *always* have on person, is his sword. But Nelson's one had a [pistol built in it](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-stoke-staffordshire-20612757).

I've been explosive at one point in history,

> [Nelson's Pillar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson's_Pillar) in Dublin was destroyed by explosion.

what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> Horatio Nelson is a well-known historical figure.

Comment: Sheesh. I'm extremely impressed by the research but unfortunately this one requires what could be considered common knowledge. Try to think in simpler terms. That can count for the hint I needed to add on this one.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> A Fuse

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,

> A fuse starts the countdown to an explosion

and just relax here at the top of my column.

> A fuse is at the top of a cannon

Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,

> A fuse makes a whistling sound

but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> Im connected to a cannon, kinda like a pistol

I've been explosive at one point in history,

> They used to use blackpowder, which is explosive

what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> Everybody knows what a fuse is

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and great answer!

Comment: I am not following your pistol logic here

Comment: Yah. Unfortunately that's missing the logic in a few spots. Keep trying. On this one and part 3 it looks like I'll need to add another hint today.

Answer (score 4):

you are

> the Big Ben

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,

> it's a clock

and just relax here at the top of my column.

> it's on top of a tower

Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,

> I bet it have many working reproduction

but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> ok, here come the stretch, i did my research and in a videogame (s.t.a.l.k.e.r.) there is a pistol called Big Ben, i wouldn' t bet on it, but since Z.Dailey already referenced videogame...

I've been explosive at one point in history,

> "exploded" in 1976

what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> everybody know about the Big Ben

Comment: Yah. No more video game references. :p. Not it.

Comment: welp, i hadn't great hope on it anyway, at least we excluded videogame reference. back on the hunt then !

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me a bit like...

> A camera flash (bulb).

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,
and just relax here at the top of my column.

> Some cameras may flash at you to display the countdown when using the delay feature.  You can mount a camera on a tripod, and the flash is mounted on top of the camera.

Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,
but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> Everyone knows that characteristic whine of a recharging flash (from movies or disposable cameras). Be careful, because cameras can and will shoot you!

Typically speaking I reach senses of three,
when you count those senses, you may find me.

> The flash (sight), pop (sound), and chemical smell of a burnt-out bulb.

For if you hold me, I'm likely dead,
why did you take me away from my bed?

> You are not likely to be holding the actual bulb unless it has burnt out and needs replacing.

I came with a flash and out like a light,
but I don't really mind because life is so bright.

> This one is pretty self-explanatory.

I've been explosive at one point in history,
what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> Flash was once achieved through the ignition of flash powder, creating a small explosion.

Comment: Good one. I was trying to fit a lightbulb, never though about this.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is:

> Hydrogen

"I'll start to count while you solve this problem,
and just relax here at the top of my column."

> 'Start to count' -> Hydrogen is element #1, also located at the top of column #1 of the periodic table.

"Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle"

> Feels far-fetched... Hydrogen is present in our atmosphere. Could refer to wind or people whistling.

"but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol."
"I've been explosive at one point in history,"

> Hydrogen is explosive.

"what I truly am is not much of a mystery."

> Hydrogen is pretty common knowledge

Comment: With the updates, it seems to be a good fit for a lot of things (30s and 40s, it can cause flashes, and the first part of the word is not good for computers. However, I can't think of how a lot of the newer additions fit this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> Dynamite (or bombs)

"I'll start to count while you solve this problem,
and just relax here at the top of my column."

> Dynamite is basically a tube with a wick and some powder-fire reactive component inside, usually (but not limited to) Trinitrotoluene and/or gunpowder

"Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,
but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol."

> When you know there is explosive material in an area, you are going to react negatively or at least exercise some grade of caution, especially if you are the one controlling it because it is very dangerous.

"I've been explosive at one point in history,
what I truly am is not much of a mystery."

> Dynamite or other generic bombs are highly explosive!

Comment: Excellent guess, but there's an answer that fits absolutely perfect. Once you think of it you'll know it's right.

Comment: it is a A Canon

Comment: That's not it either, but the standard for guesses it to either change or append your answer an make it a "spoiler" i.e. >!  Keep guessing. ;)

Comment: >! The clock ?, i'm gonna make an answer if turns out it is :)

Comment: Nope. And spoilers don't work in comments. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are ...

> a **lightning**.

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,

> People start to count when they see a lightning, to find out how far away it is (waiting for the thunder).

and just relax here at the top of my column.

> This might refer to a [Tesla coil](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_coil).

Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,

> Lightnings cause [Whistlers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistler_(radio)).

but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> There is for example the [Colt M1877 "Lightning"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colt_M1877).

I came with a flash and out like a light,

> "A flash of lightning." (from dictionary.com)

but I don't really mind because life is so bright.

> A lightning is definitely bright.

I've been explosive at one point in history,

> Lightnings can [cause explosions](https://youtu.be/9higGDEwLIg).

what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> See above. Additional hints are the titles, which as I assume are mixed up. "Large and in charge" would fit a lightning, "Small and resilient" a button, "Immovable object" a mountain and maybe "Breathing new life" for an ocarina. This would leave "Unstoppable force" for the final riddle.

Comment: Lightning isn't the answer. Sorry. Keep searching.

Answer (score 2):

You are a

> Flower.

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,
and just relax here at the top of my column. 
Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle, 
but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> Flower's have pistils...

Typically speaking I reach senses of three, 
when you count those senses, you may find me.

> The sense of smell is normally the 3rd of 5 senses listed, and the one most associated with flowers

For if you hold me, I'm likely dead, 
why did you take me away from my bed?

> Flowers grow in beds, and when you pick them, they die.

I came with a flash and out like a light, 
but I don't really mind because life is so bright.

> They appear from the dark earth suddenly and grow toward the light.

I've been explosive at one point in history, 
what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> Perhaps this is referring to the Pre-Cambrian Explosion?  When plants proliferated around the world?

Comment: This is the closest answer so far...

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> Time

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,

> Time counts up

and just relax here at the top of my column.

> Well this is the only weird sentence.

Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,

> If you let time pass, something good or bad will happen

but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> Time can heal wounds, but also cause wounds

I came with a flash and out like a light,

> The Big Bang

but I don't really mind because life is so bright.

> Time doesn't care about anything

I've been explosive at one point in history,

> Yes, the Big Bang

what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> Time is not a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've been going back and forth over whether or not to post an answer, and @Z.Dailey suggested I do so, so I think you could be

> an orchid

or maybe

> a pansy

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,
and just relax here at the top of my column.
Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,
but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> A [column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_(botany)) is a part of some flowers, specifically orchids (but not pansies), which includes the *pistil*.

Typically speaking I reach senses of three,
when you count those senses, you may find me.
For if you hold me, I'm likely dead,
why did you take me away from my bed?

> Flowers appeal to sight and smell, and can be touched (or alternately, I suppose, tasted by bees?). If you hold a flower, it has very likely been pulled or cut from the ground (a "flowerbed")

Out of the rainbow I cannot see blue,
and my name can be split into two.
The first part of me is a computer's worst dream,
while the second one comes apart at the seam.

Back in the 30's I caused a great craze,
not one single chap did I cease to amaze.
Everyone loved me and wanted a kiss,
but then in the 40's screamed "What did I miss?"

> The [Pansy Craze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansy_Craze) was a movement involving increased visibility of the gay community in Manhattan, pre-Hayes Code.

I came with a flash and out like a light,
but I don't really mind because life is so bright.
I've been explosive at one point in history,
what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> Some orchids, like the [Ghost Orchid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrophylax_lindenii), are very rare, and poached for profit. I feel like that sort of, but doesn't exactly fit the "explosive at one point in history" clue.

Comment: Well there's 2 that can be ruled out. ;) sorry @question_asker keep searching.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this answer, for several days, but it seems to fit, and not fit, at the same time.  I might as well try...

Are you a

> clover leaf or shamrock?

I'll start to count while you solve this problem,

> clovers are famous for being frequently counted, in the hopes of finding a 4-leaved one

and just relax here at the top of my column.

> clover leaves sit at the top of the clover stalk

Everywhere I go I let out a good whistle,

> a clover leaf whistle (weak)

but don't mess with me cause I carry a pistol.

> or a pistil, rather

Typically speaking I reach senses of three,

> typically they are found with 3 leaves, rather than 4, or more

when you count those senses, you may find me.
For if you hold me, I'm likely dead,
why did you take me away from my bed?

> a picked flower quickly begins to die

Out of the rainbow I cannot see blue,

> clovers come in many colors - red, green, white - but never blue

and my name can be split into two.

> clover leaf is two words - shamrock

The first part of me is a computer's worst dream,

> Clover yellow mosaic virus - a virus is a computer's worst dream
>  shamrock doesn't fit here

while the second one comes apart at the seam.

> leaves fall apart at the seams, when you mess with them
>  again, shamrock doesn't fit

Back in the 30's I caused a great craze,
not one single chap did I cease to amaze.
Everyone loved me and wanted a kiss,
but then in the 40's screamed "What did I miss?"

> Dan Sullivan's Shamrock Band?

I came with a flash and out like a light,
but I don't really mind because life is so bright.

> Clovers/Shamrocks have a short lifespan, but they grow in the sunlight.

I've been explosive at one point in history,

> [clover-leaf shaped explosions?](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2008/aug/27/cold-atoms-explode-like-cloverleafs) (weak)

what I truly am is not much of a mystery.

> Clearly a lie.  Very much a mystery!